# How to Split string In javascript Using regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, split

i am trying to do something like this

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
var wordContainer = str.split(/\b/) || 0;
document.write(wordContainer);
}

findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

but this returns

```
The, ,quick, ,brown, ,fox, ,jumped, ,over, ,the, ,lazy, ,dog
```

however if i do something like this

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
var wordContainer = str.split(" ") || 0;
document.write(wordContainer);
}

findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

it works as expected and returns

```
The,quick,brown,fox,jumped,over,the,lazy,dog
```

so why using /\b/ is different from using " " in split ?

Comment: `\b` is a word boundary, and a space matches the space. So, there is nothing strange in the results you get.

Comment: Also your defaulting case is useless as  split will always return an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `" "` is a literal space, and `\b` is a word boundary.

Word boundaries occur before the first character in a string, if the first character is a word character, and then again after the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character, and also between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character, meaning your string looks like this with the boundaries :

```
"The\b \bquick\b \bbrown\b \bfox\b \bjumped\b \bover\b \bthe\b \blazy\b \bdog"
```

In other words, you're matching the `\b` at the beginning of the word, and at the end of the word, and you're getting the spaces as well, as you're splitting, and end up with

`["The"," ","quick"," ","brown"," ","fox"," ","jumped"," ","over"," ","the"," ","lazy"," ","dog"]`

If you want to split words on boundaries, you have to add both of them, and anything in the middle, as in `/\b.\b/`

Comment: Perfect answer , now i got where i was wrong .thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

`\b` a Matches a zero-width word boundary, such as between a letter and a space.

while using `split(' ')` only matches spaces:

[Docs on Regex from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)